# Debugging a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, variables, for-loop

I've been looking throught the documentation, but can't seem to find the bit I want.

I have a for loop and I would like to be able to view every value in the for loop.

for example here is a part of my code:

```
for d = 1 : nb
            %for loop performs blade by blade averaging and produces a column vector
            for cc = navg : length(atbmat);
                atb2 = (sum(atbmat((cc-(navg-1):cc),d)))/navg;
                atbvec2(:,cc) = atb2;
            end
            %assigns column vector 'atbvec2' to the correct column of the matrix 'atbmat2'
            atbmat2(d,1:length(atbvec2)) = atbvec2;
        end
```

I would like to view every value of atb2. I'm a python user(new to MATLAB) and would normally use a simple `print` statement to find this.

I'm sure there is a way to do it, but I can't quite find how.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `disp` in Matlab to print to the screen but you might want to use `sprintf` first to format it nicely. However for debugging you're better off using a break point and then inspect the variable in the [workspace browser](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-workspace.html) graphically. To me, this is one of Matlab's best features.

Have a look at the "Examine Values" section of [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-199)

Comment: You don't even need `disp`, just write the name of the variable on its own (without a semicolon), and MATLAB will output its value to the command window.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to view it everywhere is to change this line:

```
atb2 = (sum(atbmat((cc-(navg-1):cc),d)))/navg;
```

Into this, without semicolon:

```
atb2 = (sum(atbmat((cc-(navg-1):cc),d)))/navg
```

That being said, given the nature of your calculation, you could get the information you need as well by simply storing every value of abt2 and observing them afterwards. This may be done in `atbmat2` already?

If you want to look at each value at the time it happens, consider setting a breakpoint or conditional breakpoint after the line where `abt2` is assigned.